# Have trouble figuring out the command to pull data from several tables

Tags: mysql

I don't even know how to search for this.

I have a database I am trying to pull data from 4 tables.

First I get the list of categories from the animal_list table.

Then I use a while loop to pull the animals from the animal table that match up with the category.

That works fine.  It displays all the animal data broken down into the three categories.

Now I'm trying to get animal attributes from 2 other databases.  So I need it to take the animal_id and search through the skill_per_char table where it would find the skill ID linked up with the animal_id and skill_id, it then needs to search through the skills table and pull out the name for the skill matching the id.

I tried using separate SQL calls but it wouldn't display every skill for each animal just the first one, and it would give an error for everything else that didn't have a skill.  So I tried adding in another while loop where I want the data to appear and it would not show the skill for the animals with the skills and would then give errors for everything else.  So I tried a for loop, for each animal search for the skills and display them, that just went nuts and I have set up error reporting to an email.  I ended up with 3500 errors all the same.  It was continuing so I had to kill the process.

I've done a lot with this sort of thing, and it normally works, but this time some animals have more than one skill so I have to do a while loop for those but I just can't get it to work.

Thanks

[[[[EDIT]]]]

I fixed the problem.  It might not be the correct way to do it, but it works.

Here is what I did:

```
$g = "SELECT * FROM animal_list";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $g) or trigger_error("Query: $g\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

while ($ani = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$b = "SELECT * FROM animal WHERE group_id = {$ani['group_id']}";
$B = mysqli_query($dbc, $b) or trigger_error("Query: $b\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


echo '<div style="float: left; padding: 20px;">

<table width="800" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">';
echo '<tr><td colspan="13" align="center"><b>' . $ani['group'] . '</b></td></tr>';
echo '<tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Name:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><b>Skills:</b></td>
            </tr>';
    while ($animal = mysqli_fetch_array($B, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td align="left">' . $animal['name'] .'</td>
            <td align="left">';

            $a = "SELECT skill_id FROM skill_per_char WHERE char_id = {$animal['animal_id']}";
            $A = mysqli_query($dbc, $a) or trigger_error("Query: $a\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($A) > 0) {
                while ($aniskill = mysqli_fetch_array($A)) {

                $k = "SELECT name FROM skills WHERE skill_id = {$aniskill['skill_id']}";
            $K = mysqli_query($dbc, $k) or trigger_error("Query: $k\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

            $askill = mysqli_fetch_array($K);

                echo '' . $askill['name'] . ' ';    
                }
            }
            echo '</td>
            </tr>';
}
    echo '</table></div>';
}
```

I know tables are bad, but this works for my output.  I deleted the other field data.  There are a total of 12 values in the animal database.

Anyway this works, thanks everyone.

Comment: If you provide table structures in readable format with result you want to achieve, it would be much better.

Comment: Look into the SQL commands JOIN and INNER JOIN and RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Comment: I updated my question with the answer I came up with and the code I used to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [JOINS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) in sql. There are plenty of joins tutorials available. Keep studying. MySQL supports inner, left, right and cross joins.

Comment: I work with joins I guess I don't know everything about them.  I didn't know how to pull all data from the animal table, then take the animal_id from there and match it with the char_id in the skill_per_char table.  Then get the skill_id from the skills_per_char id and match it with the skill_id from the skills table to get the skill name.  I didn't know you could have a WHERE char_id = animal_id and then WHERE skill_id = skill_id.  Maybe if I added another table or changed animal_id to char_id, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the select statement to give you what you are looking for might look something like this:

```
SELECT  a.animal_name, s.skill_name

FROM    animals AS a

        JOIN skill_per_char AS spc ON a.animal_id = spc.char_id
        JOIN skills AS s ON spc.skill_id = s.skill_id

ORDER BY a.animal_name, s.skill_name;
```